# Make ng-repeat for img in carousel

Tags: html, angularjs

I have working example of carousel in angularJS

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner container">


            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="img-fluid myImgClass imgMargin center-img d-block" src="/Content/FilesBlog/23.11.2018/85/GBP.png"
                    alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="img-fluid myImgClass imgMargin center-img d-block" src="/Content/FilesBlog/23.11.2018/85/GBP.png"
                    alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="img-fluid myImgClass imgMargin center-img d-block" src="/Content/FilesBlog/23.11.2018/85/GBP.png"
                    alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

But I need to do it in next way: click on little photo on post and will open modal with all photo of post. I know how to do modal. I have problem with ng-repeat and ng-class

My code

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner container">
            {{item = 0}}
            <div ng-repeat="img in imgModal"
                 ng-class="item == 0 && carousel-item active || item >= 0 && carousel-item">
                <img class="img-fluid myImgClass imgMargin center-img d-block"
                     src="{{img}}" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            {{item + 1}}

        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

And in result I have no carousel. All Imgs goes under each other such a simple div in html. What I must do that it is work good?!

Comment: Please include an [mcve]

Comment: SInce the "⏪" icon and the "⏩" icon don't have any `ng-click` directives, my guess is that you are using a jQuery library for the carousel. When you mix AngularJS and jQuery like this, you are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing logic only to ng-class where ng-class works off of object-like syntax for "if":"then" scenarios. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#examples

The ng-class syntax is similar to {"if this logic thing is true" : "then apply these classes"}

You also only need ng-class for the classes that will dynamically change/update. Since all div's have "carousel-item" as a class, it does not need ng-class.

Lastly, you will need to store your images in some sort of object to keep track of which one is active or is not active (or keep track of activeImage in a different variable).

**Controller:**

```
imgModal = [
{src: 'example/source.jpg', active: true},
{src: 'example/source.jpg', active: false},
{src: 'example/source.jpg', active: false}
];
```

**Template:**

```
        <div class="carousel-inner container">
            <div ng-repeat="img in imgModal"
                 class="carousel-item"
                 ng-class="{
                        'img.active': 'active'
                 }">
                <img
                    class="img-fluid myImgClass imgMargin center-img d-block"
                    ng-src="{{img.src}}" />
            </div>
        </div>
```